# help on expanding xml and getting attribute values to textbox vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, textbox, windows-xp

Newbie looking for help on getting xml http response in vb.net
this is what im looking to do ,getting these attributes `values(Red,Green,Yellow,Black)` to a 4 different textbox's on vb.net project.any help learning this would be very helpfull.
thanks

```
<system ver="1.0">
<colors>
<type red="Red" green="Green" yellow="Yellow" Black="Black" />
</colors>
</system>
```

Here is what I have so far,and tried different ways but always ending up erasing it.:(

```
 Sub GetData()


        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("target url")
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        If response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then

          Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            ' Create a reader for the stream object
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
            ' Read from the stream object using the reader, put the contents in a string
            Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            ' Create a new, empty XML document
            Dim HttpResult As New XmlDocument
            Dim UserInfo As XmlNodeList
            Dim Discription As XmlNode
            HttpResult = New XmlDocument
            HttpResult.LoadXml(contents)


            'Create the XML Document
            HttpResult = New XmlDocument()
            Dim _XPath As String =
            UserInfo = HttpResult.SelectNodes("")



            'Get the Gender Attribute Value
            Dim DetailsAttribute = Discription.Attributes.GetNamedItem("").Value
     endif

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with this...

```
Dim MyDoc as New System.Xml.XmlDocument
MyDoc.Load("c:\path\to\your\xml\file")

Dim MyNode as System.Xml.XmlNode = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//system/colors/type")

Dim RedAttribute as String = MyNode.Attributes("red").Value
Dim GreenAttribute as String = MyNode.Attributes("green").Value
Dim YellowAttribute as String = MyNode.Attributes("yellow").Value
Dim BlackAttribute as String = MyNode.Attributes("black").Value
```

I think that should get you where you want to go.

Comment: well thanks:) that worked fine 
i had to add myDoc.loadxml cause it added other illegal characters to it without it.
only issue now is ,it says it cant convert the red,green.. attributes to a string.any ideas on how to convert it to string?

again thanks alot for the help!